# My app Going Crash in api 22 but 23 is Working Fine?

Tags: android

My APP Going Crash In Android API 22
and it working fine in marshmallow .

my App gradle file is

[image]
[image: Gradle[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPwrX.png)

Comment: what is the crash, logs add more details to rectify the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately stop in particular activity in the appp

Comment: Post the crash logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i salve this after 2 days

my xml property was wrong that was working in massmellow
but not in other version so

i set textcolor attribute was tekan wrong peramiter .